# Binding does not trigger event in ViewController using MVVM in Swift 4

Tags: swift, mvvm

I am trying to learn binding and understand the MVVM approach in Swift.

I was expecting the below example to work, essentially `someEventHappened` is called, this invokes the `onEvent` closure and my message is logged to the screen.

This does not happen however, nothing is printed and I am a little unsure as to why?

```
class ViewModal { 
    public var onEvent: (() -> Void)?
    func someEventHappened() -> Void {
        onEvent?()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var viewModel: ViewModal = {
        let viewModal = ViewModal()
        return viewModal
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        viewModel.someEventHappened()
        viewModel.onEvent = {
            print("something happened")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap assigning `onEvent` and calling `someEventHappened`

```
viewModel.onEvent = {
    print("something happened")
}
viewModel.someEventHappened()
```

this is because you're calling `onEvent` handler inside `someEventHappened` and in `viewDidLoad` you first had called `someEventHappened` and then assigned `onEvent`